# Don't get subscription plan using in_app_purchase dependency flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, in-app-purchase, subscription

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUxNB.jpg)

in_app_purchase throw error [purchaseId] not found so what I do?
I am using `in_app_purchase: ^3.1.1`

I get all the producers from the play console but not the subscriptions.

I try both of purchasePlanId and basePlanId but get same error **[id]not found**

Comment: Do you set your product item to public in developer console?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: provide created subscription screenshot of play console.